# IE, HTML issues when running the site on lamp

Tags: html, css

is there any difference in parsing of HTML / CSS , from a windows server and an apache linux server.

The issue is, I have my site working fine (as it should) on Internet Explorer when I am running it on a dev environment on windows (wamp) server.

The same thing doesn't work when I open the site in IE ,while it is deployed on linux environment.

I have checked so far there is not any major difference, what i suspect is that the css file has some parse errors and maybe linux has some big issues with it.

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=demo.behoover.com%3A8001&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

http://demo.behoover.com:8001

If you run this on IE, you notice, the font breaks, the header has an ugly margin, the form alignment is out.

form alignment is fixable, but the other 2 , I got no clue off

---

OK, i just looked a bit more and found this , When i try to access the site from the linux server , it shows me the DocumentMode as IE7

[image]

but from my local server, it shows me by default

```
DocumentMode IE8 standards
```

btw I am running it on IE8 and IE7 , but not greater

Comment: im gonna make some changes to the question, i just found something , i think its only IE 7

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference in the content served based on platform (unless there is specific logic for that purpose). However, the location of the site you are addressing can trigger different compatibility view policies in IE.

Depending on where the site is hosted (i.e. local machine versus intranet or internet) a different policy may be applied, which would give exactly the behavior described.

[image: Screenshot]

For what it's worth, when I brought up the site in Chrome and IE 9 it looked fine. IE 9 ran as it should (correct mode, no compatibility triggered). IE 8 (emulation) looked a little less polished but the page layout was correct and no compatibility mode triggered. However, IE 7 had font/alignment issues no matter what mode I used, so that may be the bigger issue.

Comment: heh, but this is on my own desktop.. what about other users :) 
.. anyways.. i think i should fix the site for IE7,

Comment: I know you can't change user settings...I was just giving a possible reason for the difference that only you would notice switching between public/private. For public sites it's usually not an issue. And yes, I think there are IE 7 problems regardless of compat view settings.